# How can I describe the glass stuck diagonally and those in a straight row?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, image-identification

I'm not able to find proper words to describe these three pictures:

> [image: three pictures of glasses]

If I try to describe them myself, then my sentences would be:

1. [.........]
2. Glasses are in a straight row.
   Imperative: Keep these glasses in a straight row.
3. The yellow glass stuck in the middle diagonally.
   Imperative: Stick the yellow glass diagonally.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Stacked*
2. *Lined up; in a row*
3. Depends on use:
   formal - *askew*
   informal - *wonky*

Answers may vary by location; I'm from the southern region of the U.S.

Comment: Askew and wonky may not be the best choices.  I would use the simpler and more common, "wedged."

Answer (score 0):

### 1. on top of each other

When you place one object on top of another you are **stacking** them. Usually, having a flat surface makes stacking easier; e.g. **"a stack of papers"**. If there is more than one stack then add the -s suffix, e.g. "stacks of books".

[image]

Sometimes the objects can be hollow (like bowls), so they can fit snugly inside one another. If the objects are not stackable, and most coffee cups with handles are not,  then the word **pile** is appropriate. Notice in the OP's image, the cups *appear* to be stacked but they are not. In real life, if the same three cups were placed **on top of each other** the resulting pile would *wobble* and might collapse.

[image]

*a pile of dirty dishes*

### 2. behind one another

A line of objects, for instance the seats in a movie theatre, seen lengthwise would be called a row, **a row of seats**. In the OP's example, I would say that the glasses are seen **in a line**, in an **[Indian file](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/indian_file)** ,or perhaps less controversially, **a single file**. In other words, the glasses are *behind one another*

### 3. one inside another

In picture 3, the smaller glass is *inside* the larger glass, but it is not *nested* comfortably. The yellow glass is **stuck**<sup>[2.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stick#h70171429627960)</sup>,  **wedged** or **[jammed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jam)** inside the larger glass.

The famous matryoshka doll is also known as a Russian **nesting** doll, and  **Stacking** doll

> …is a set of wooden dolls of decreasing size placed one inside another.

[image]